# Resizing a starling mobile game to fit multiple resolutions.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air, starling-framework

I have a game written in AS3 using the Starling framework. It's built for mobile so supporting lots of screens is really important. I have written all of my code to support many sizes but I am hitting a snag and I can't seem to find the solution on the web.

The stage rescaling and Asset rescaling is working great, but the problem is this line:

```
[SWF(framerate="60", width="768", height="1024", backgroundColor="0x333333")]
```

Setting the SWF size makes the application permanently thinks it is on a display that is 768 x 1024. So if I run it on an iPhone instead of an ipad, the app will run but will only fill the first 1024px height and will run over the 640px width. However if I hardcode the line above with the iPhone resolution it will look great. So my question is how can this be done dynamically? I have tried the resize event listener with no luck. As I say my issue is not in the stage but rather in the init of the SWF. Below is my entire initialization class. Please let me know what it is that I am missing! Thanks!

```
[SWF(framerate="60", width="768", height="1024", backgroundColor="0x333333")]

public class FlappyBird2 extends Sprite
{
    private var myStarling:Starling;

    public function FlappyBird2()
    {
        super();
        stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Capabilities.screenResolutionX, Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

        var viewPortRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        viewPortRectangle.width = stage.stageWidth;
        viewPortRectangle.height = stage.stageHeight;

        trace("screen res: X: "+ Capabilities.screenResolutionX + "Y: " + Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
        myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage, viewPortRectangle);
        myStarling.antiAliasing = 1;
        myStarling.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. you just need to have the SCALE_FACTOR division if your're working with multi resolutions, otherwise remove the division.

```
  var viewPort : Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);

  //create the main instance of starling
  engine = new Starling(_root, stage, viewPort);

  //main configs
  engine.stage.stageWidth     = viewPort.width / SCALE_FACTOR;
  engine.stage.stageHeight    = viewPort.height / SCALE_FACTOR;
```

I hope that this will help you. 
There's an interesting tutorial under here http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/multi-resolution_development as well; otherwise you should check the Starling Forum they have a lot of these similar issues over there.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the scaling thing will not get you very far.

There are many ways to solve this problem, but usually it involves following some MVC pattern, separating logic and data from UI painting.

Once you have done that you can either:

- Make a different view for every screen resolution via code or configurations files
- Make the UI painting dynamic, so that it adapts to any resolution and screen DPI

Depending on you project one of those options (or a combination) will suit you better.

Comment: How would I use the config files for the different screen resolutions?

Comment: I am already using a MVC pattern and my application handles UI outside of logic, That part works fine, it is the configuration for different screens that I am having issue with. How would I use the config files for the different screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

Just turn this:

`[SWF(framerate="60", width="768", height="1024", backgroundColor="0x333333")]`

to this:

`[SWF( frameRate="60", backgroundColor="0x333333")]`

;)